# Ext JS, change grid column configs default values globally

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs-grid

Ext.grid.column.Column class has following configs:

- **draggable** (Defaults to: true)
- **sortable** (Defaults to: true)
- **menuDisabled** (Defaults to: false)

Is it possible to change default values of this configs globally for all grid columns in my application ?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, using Ext.override......

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext-method-override

example...

```
Ext.override(Ext.grid.column.Column, {
 draggable: true,
 sortable: true,
 menuDisabled: false
});
```

Comment: draggable, sortable, menuDisabled are configs of 'Ext.grid.column.Column' class, not configs of 'Ext.grid.Panel' class. 

Here you can see working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Yoh0xFF/dd7huux5/1/

Answer (score 4):

Given that the accepted answer is for ExtJS 5.x, I thought it would be useful to have an answer for ExtJS 4.x too.

Something like the following should do it:

```
  Ext.define('Ext.my.grid.column.Column', {
    override : 'Ext.grid.column.Column',
    draggable : false,
    sortable : false,
    menuDisabled : true
  });
```

Now every time you use a column in a grid, it will take these as defaults.