# Set default column config "menuDisabled" in Ext JS class definition

Tags: extjs

In ExtJS 5.1, I would like to define a class extending Ext.grid.Panel that sets defaults for columns, specifically the menuDisabled property.  I do not want this set for all grids, just this class.  In Ext 5 this property was changed to a column specific property and you can set the default in a grid config this way:

```
columns: {
    defaults: { menuDisabled: true },
    items: [...]
}
```

How do I set this in a class definition so that users of this class do not have to set it?  I've tried different incantations like:

```
Ext.define('MyGridPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    menuDisabled: true
});
```

and

```
Ext.define('MyGridPanel', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    defaults: {
        columns: {
            menuDisabled: true
        }
    }
});
```

I was able to get it to change globally for all grids using the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30003973/2525213), but I want to set it just for my grid class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either cpastore84's answer or maybe better the following way because it does not impose the limitation of the `columns` configuration having to be an array at all times:

```
Ext.define('MenuDisabledGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    initComponent: function() {
        this.callParent(arguments);
        this.headerCt.items.each(function(c){
            c.menuDisabled = true;
        });
    }
});
```

Doing it through `initComponent` seems to be unavoidable because in the `Ext.panel.Table`'s source code the header is created this way:

```
me.headerCt = new Ext.grid.header.Container(headerCtCfg);
```

instead of

```
me.headerCt = Ext.create(headerCtCfg);
```

In the latter case we could do it all declaratively by specifying a custom header config in the `MenuDisabledGrid` class definition.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a better way, but one way to achieve this would be to override your component's `initComponent` method like this:

```
initComponent : function () {
    // for each column
    Ext.Array.each(this.columns, function (col) {

       // set menuDisabled to true
        Ext.apply(col, {
            menuDisabled : true
        });

    });

    this.callParent(arguments);
}
```